# Operate in the files of a directory in Windows script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I want to create a script to convert odts to pdfs with Libreoffice so I created the following script:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.odt) do (
            soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf "%%~nf.odt"
)
```

But this is slow because it can create many processes. So I want to do the following:

```
soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf file1 file2 file3 .... filen
```

and process all the files with a command invocation.

Comment: Hmm.  That code in theory should only convert one file at a time. Only one process should be running at a time.

Comment: No, it works. I have tried it.

Comment: Then I would try using the `START` command with the `/WAIT` option or use the `CALL` command when launching soffice.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Build the file list first, then call the converter:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set filelist=
for %%f in (*.odt) do (
            set "filelist=!filelist! "%%~nf.odt""
)
soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf %filelist%
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted.

Comment: @arcad, if you have many files to convert this could fail because you are limited to the line length of 8192 fore the execution of a cmd.